# ¿Por qué ++(*p) cambia el valor del puntero?

Tags: c++

Dado el código

```
int A[5] = {2,1,3,55};
int *p = A;
cout << ++(*p);
```

El resultado en la pantalla es 3 y el valor en A[0] es 3 ambient, ¿por qué?

Creí que con la jerarquia de operadores () debía operarse primero que el ++, entonces obtendríamos:

```
++(*p) => ++(2) => 3
```

sin ningun cambio en el valor primero de A.

Answer (score 6):

Tu código en ningún momento cambia el valor del puntero (tu variable `p`):

```
int A[5] = { 2, 1, 3, 55 };
int *p = A;

cout << p << ": " << ++(*p) << '\n';
cout << p << '\n';
```

> 0x7ffc8f9da430: 3
> 0x7ffc8f9da430

Lo que si cambia es **aquello apuntado por `p`**. Lo cual es justamente lo que tiene que pasar, puesto que los punteros se usan precisamente para eso: contener direcciones de memoria y poder trabajar de manera indirecta con lo que allí se encuentre.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que preguntas por qué cambia el valor apuntado, y no el puntero, ya que en realidad el puntero no cambia, como Trauma ha explicado en su respuesta.

El problema es el uso del operador `++` ya que de la misma forma que `++i` incrementa el valor de la variable `i` *y la modifica*, al guardar el resultado en la misma variable, lo mismo ocurre si en vez de `i` pones la dirección apuntada por un puntero, esto es `++(*p)`.

Para sumar 1 a lo que hay, *sin cambiar la variable*, de la misma forma que escribirías `i+1`, puedes escribir en este caso:

```
cout << (*p)+1;
```

Los paréntesis no serían necesarios en este caso, pero los añado por claridad.